# How can I remove a downvote?

Tags: support, editing, down-votes, voting

After a clarifying discussion I see that my downvote was not necessary.
Do I have to wait until the post is edited and then upvote or is there another possibility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you catch it within 5 minutes of making the vote, yes, you have to wait until the post is edited. If you see something that can be improved about the post, you can suggest an edit yourself.

Comment: Mind you, trivial edits *just* so that you can change a vote are discouraged. Please try to *improve* the post in the process.